# Why is my python program skipping the input function

Tags: python

```py
responses = {}

# Set a flag to indicate that polling is active
polling_active = True

while polling_active:
    # Prompt for the person's name and response.
    name = input('\nWhat is your name? ')
    response = input('Which mountain would you like to climb someday? ')

# store the response in the dictionary.
responses[name] = response

# Find out if anyone else is going to take the poll.
repeat = input('\nWould you like to let another person respond? (yes/no)')
if repeat.lower == 'no':
    polling_active = False

# Polling is complete.Show results.
print('---Poll Results---')
for name, response in responses.items():
    print(f'{name} would like to climb {response}.')
```

> And the result is:-

```
What is your name? Jake
Which mountain would you like to climb someday? Mount Fuji
What is your name?
```

The problem is it is not asking for another person response. This function is in repeat variable and it should ask for' Would you like to let another person respond? (yes/no)' after asking for which mountain to climb.

'

Comment: Because `polling_active` is still `True`.

Comment: you have to indent your code so that if falls under the while loop

Comment: You have to indent your code from line number 11 - 17 so that it works like expected. Otherwise the same question is asked over and over again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
responses = {}

#Set a flag to indicate that polling is active
polling_active = True

while polling_active:
    # Prompt for the person's name and response.
    name = input('\nWhat is your name? ')
    response = input('Which mountain would you like to climb someday? ')


    ### THE LINES BELOW NEED TO BE INDENTED ###

    #store the response in the dictionary.
    responses[name] = response

    #Find out if anyone else is going to take the poll.
    repeat = input('\nWould you like to let another person respond? (yes/no)')
    if repeat.lower() == 'no':  # changed to lower()
        polling_active = False

    ### UNTIL THIS LINE ###


# Polling is complete.Show results.
print('---Poll Results---')
for name,response in responses.items():   # changed to items()
    print(f'{name} would like to climb {response}.')
```

Answer (score 0):

you missed a indent on `responses[name] = response` and next 3 line thats why your script is going to repeat first input

```py
responses = {}

# Set a flag to indicate that polling is active
polling_active = True

while polling_active:
    # Prompt for the person's name and response.
    name = input('\nWhat is your name? ')
    response = input('Which mountain would you like to climb someday? ')

    # store the response in the dictionary.
    responses[name] = response

    # Find out if anyone else is going to take the poll.
    repeat = input('\nWould you like to let another person respond? (yes/no)')
    if repeat.lower() == 'no':
        polling_active = False

# Polling is complete.Show results.
print('---Poll Results---')
for name, response in responses.items():
    print(f'{name} would like to climb {response}.')
```

Comment: `repeat.lower` won't work. It has to be lower()

Comment: yes i edited and i wasn't checking any other errors i just answered the question

Answer (score -2):

Since `polling_active = True` is always `True` and hence it is never coming out of while loop.

You need to set `polling_active = False`

After you have taken the first person interview, probably it is better to write a function and call it.